# Ancestor of all living humans / Ancestor of no living humans

Tags: exponential-function, population-dynamics

I recall reading somewhere that after sufficient number of generations have passed, you will either be the ancestor of all living humans or the ancestor of no living humans. Is this true? If so, how would we prove it?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Well, they will both be true eventually when all humans have gone extinct, but it isn't necessarily true in all ideal settings where mankind is allowed to survive indefinitely: consider the case where there are two populations that live sparately forever.